# Checking values in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have simple JavaScript question.

I have an array (xyz) of 9 objects (Cell), each with 2 properties (e,v).

Is there any easy way to check if all the values of one of the properties are false?

Something like:

```
var myArray = xyz[];

if(all myArray.e==false){
    do this;
}
```

---

Thanks :D

```
Array[9]
0:Cell
 e:false
 v:"x"
1:Cell
2:Cell
3:Cell
4:Cell
...etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [JavaScript Array every() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_every.asp)

```
var myArray = [xyz];
if (myArray.every(obj => !obj.e)) {
   do this;
}
```

Comment: I agree. Can you add some explanation or a snippet?

Comment: Thanks, this looks very simple and useful.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with the `reduce` function.

Try:

```
const areAllFalse = !myArray.reduce((prev, cur) => prev || cur, false)
```

Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for `reduce` for more info on how it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

```
let areAllFalse = true;
for (let obj in myArray){
    if (e.v) {
       areAllFalse = false;
       break;
    }
}
if (areAllFalse){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Basically:

- You instantiate a variable (in this snippet is called `areAllFalse`) to true (you are assuming that all the elements will be false)
- Then you cycle them all
- If at least one is true, you change the value of that variable and exit from the cycle as it's useles to continue
- If the variable `areAllFalse` is true, every element in the array is false, so you can execute your code

This will work in every programming language (with the obvious syntax changes)

I hope I helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a few different ways you could approach this. One way would be by using 
`every`. ([MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every))

```
function myTest(thisItem) {
    return !thisItem.e;
}

var myArray = [
    {e: false, v: 111},
    {e: false, v: 222},
    {e: false, v: 333}
];

var output = myArray.every(myTest);

console.log(output);
// expected output: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array#every` with to check for your condition to be true for all the objects in your array. Use `Object#keys` to iterate over keys in an object and check for false value using `array#some`.

```js
var arr = [{e:false, v:'x'}, {e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'}],
    result = arr.every(o => Object.keys(o).some(k => !o[k]));
console.log(result);
```

To check for `e` property in your object, you should first check if `e` key exists in the object then check if its value is false.

```js
var arr = [{e:false, v:'x'}, {e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'},{e:false, v:'x'}],
    result = arr.every(o => 'e' in o && !o.e);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks nice and elegant, but is it checking for arr.e values or for any key values ?
If I have 
`var arr = [{e:true, v:false}, {e:false, v:false}]` 
result will still be true.

Comment: It is checking for any value in object. Do you want to just check for e value?

Comment: Yes only one of the properties (e), the rest can all be true or false, or any other value.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options to do that, like

1. Normal for loop
2. ForEach loop
3. Or any looping mechanism using that you can check whether it contains a false property.

But for short answer I think you can use findIndex that will return index if it matches condition:
Example :

```
if(xyz.findIndex(k => k.e== false) > -1){
console.log("it contains false value also");
}
```